# Как правильно вызвать метод, чтобы не возникала ошибка компиляции?

Tags: c#

Как правильно вызвать метод SomeWork(), чтобы не возникала ошибка компиляции?

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ 
    interface IA  { 
        void SomeWork();
    }
    class B : IA
    {
        void IA.SomeWork() { 
            Console.WriteLine("Some work in B"); 
        } 
    }
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            B a = new B(); a.SomeWork();   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно привести экземпляр класса к интерфейсу.

```
B a = new B(); ((IA)a).SomeWork();
```

Или сразу сохранить в интерфейсе:

```
IA a = new B(); 
a.SomeWork();
```